# How can I execute a Julia script using MPI?

Tags: julia, mpi

I am trying to work through [this](https://juliaparallel.github.io/MPI.jl/stable/examples/04-sendrecv/) `helloworld` MPI example using Julia, but I get the following error message:

```sh
mpirun was unable to find the specified executable file, and therefore
did not launch the job.  This error was first reported for process
rank 0; it may have occurred for other processes as well.
```

Does this mean that `mpirun` doesn't recognize `helloworld.jl` (this is what I called my Julia script) as the executable? Or is the problem that `mpirun` doesn't recognize `julia` as the executable? The command I am executing is `mpirun -np 2 julia helloworld.jl`. I have also tried `mpiexec -n 2 julia helloworld.jl`, but I get the same error message. I have Julia 1.5.2 installed on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS. Could somebody point me in the right direction?

Comment: it suggests `mpirun` does not find `julia`. Try using the full pathname to `julia` instead.

Comment: Thanks! I updated my `.bashrc` to include an environment variable, but now it seems like `mpiexecjl` is not recognized. I already ran `MPI.install_mpiexecjl()`. Any idea what could be going wrong?

Comment: does `mpiexec -n 2 julia helloworld.jl` works? i do not expect this to complain about `mpiexecjl`. what about a simple (aka singleton mode) `julia helloworld.jl` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question in the comments, by default, the `mpiexecjl` command will not work as you are experiencing. You need to follow the steps detailed here: https://juliaparallel.github.io/MPI.jl/stable/configuration/ in order to have use of those commands from the terminal. Specifically, you need to make sure you have installed MPI per these instructions: https://juliaparallel.github.io/MPI.jl/stable/configuration/#Building

I can reproduce the mpiexecjl command not working as well even after running the `MPI.install_mpiexecjl()` in Julia. Following the install steps I linked above resolves this for me locally.

Comment: Thanks! I added another environment variable to my `.bashrc` to point to the location of the `mpiexecjl` executable, and now everything works.